# How to stop file transferring in spring-batch

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-batch

I have created a spring-batch job for reading files from local directory and upload it to remote directory through ftp using Camel-spring-batch. I am doing the same using chunk.
My spring batch job configuration looks like :

```
<bean id="consumerTemplate" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultConsumerTemplate" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="camelContext"/>
</bean>

<bean id="producerTemplate" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate" scope="step" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="camelContext"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localFileReader" class="com.camel.springbatch.reader.LocalFileReader" scope="step" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="file:#{jobParameters['dirPath']}"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="consumerTemplate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ftpFileWriter" class="com.camel.springbatch.writer.FtpFileWriter" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg ref="producerTemplate"/>
    <constructor-arg value="ftp://#{jobParameters['host']}?username=#{jobParameters['user']}&amp;password=#{jobParameters['password']}"/>
</bean>
```

Job configuration :

```
<batch:job id="ftpReadWrite">
    <batch:step id="readFromLocalWriteToFtp" next="readFromFtpWriteToLocal">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="localFileReader" writer="ftpFileWriter"  commit-interval="5" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

And my "Localfilereader" and "ftpFileWriter" looks like :

```
import org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.spring.batch.support.CamelItemReader;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LocalFileReader extends CamelItemReader {
private Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
String endpointUri;

public LocalFileReader(ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate, String endpointUri) {
    super(consumerTemplate, endpointUri);
    this.consumerTemplate=consumerTemplate;
    this.endpointUri=endpointUri;
}

@Override
public Object read() throws Exception {
    Object item = consumerTemplate.receiveBody(endpointUri);
    return item;
}
```

}

"Ftp File Writer"

```
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.component.spring.batch.support.CamelItemWriter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.List;
public class FtpFileWriter extends CamelItemWriter {
private Logger log= LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
String endpointUri;
public FtpFileWriter(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, String endpointUri) {
    super(producerTemplate, endpointUri);
    this.producerTemplate=producerTemplate;
    this.endpointUri=endpointUri;
}

@Override
public void write(List items) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("************************Writing item to ftp "+items);
    for (Object item : items) {
        System.out.println("writing item [{}]..."+item);
        producerTemplate.sendBody(endpointUri, item);
        log.debug("wrote item");
    }
}
}
```

It works fine if I have only 5 file in my local directory. It read the all 5 file from my local directory and it send to the writer and writer send it to the ftp server as my commit-interval=5. If I have 6 file in in local directory then it send first chunk of 5 file to writer and again it start reading the remaining file and this time there is only one file remaining. It read 1 file and start waiting for 4 files and never send to writer. I tried it with commit-interval=1 now it send all 6 files to server and again start waiting for next file. Here I need to stop the process once all file have been processed.

Please help me to resolved this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ConsumerTemplate`'s javadoc `receiveBody` waits until there is a response; you need to work with timeout (check TimeoutPolicy in spring-batch) or a different way to mark reader as 'exhausted' (return null from reader) to stop reader from reading

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried following policy : DefaultResultCompletionPolicy
SimpleCompletionPolicy
TimeoutTerminationPolicy
like  chunk-completion-policy="policy". But it did not worked...

Comment: I could  not find the way by which I can determine that All files have been read from a directory so that I could return "null".

Comment: I don't understand why you define your own LocalFileReader instead of reuse CamelItemReader bacause you have no gain (furthermore
,in xml contructor-arg are swapped!).  
Try using MultiResourceItemReader or [FilesInDirectoryItemReader](https://code.google.com/p/springbatch-in-action/source/browse/trunk/sbia/ch09/src/main/java/com/manning/sbia/ch09/restart/FilesInDirectoryItemReader.java?spec=svn201&r=201) or use `consumerTemplate.receiveBody(endpointUri);` but version with timeout.  
I can't help more, sorry.

Comment: I have implemented my own LocalFileReader so I can have the control. The code is same as it in CamelItemReader.
Thanks for you reply.....

Comment: I have the next step for revers functionality like read the file from ftp and write it to local. Now I am defining the timeout but once it connect to the server it reading same file again and again. Any idea how I can fix it. I am again using CamelItemReader to read file from ftp server

Answer (score 1):

You could use [receiveBodyNoWait](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ConsumerTemplate.html) instead of receiveBody.
Then you have to check if there are files remaining inside the consumer endpoint. I code this for a tasklet that consumes big-xml file into smaller pieces.

The tasklet :

```
public class MyCamelTasklet extends ServiceSupport implements Tasklet, InitializingBean{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCamelTasklet.class);

private final CamelContext camelContext;
private final ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
private final File workingDir;
private final Route xmlSplitRoute;


public MyCamelTasklet(ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate) {
    super();        
    this.consumerTemplate = consumerTemplate;
    this.camelContext = consumerTemplate.getCamelContext();     
    this.xmlSplitRoute = this.camelContext.getRoutes().get(0);
    this.workingDir = new File(xmlSplitRoute.getRouteContext().getFrom().getUri().replace("file:", ""));
}

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
        throws Exception {

    LOG.debug("reading new item...");

    Endpoint endpointXmlSplitRoute = xmlSplitRoute.getEndpoint();

    while(getNbFilesToConsume(this.workingDir) > 0) {       

     consumerTemplate.receiveBodyNoWait(endpointXmlSplitRoute);

    }       

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

private int getNbFilesToConsume(File workingDir){
    return FileUtils.listFiles(workingDir, new String[]{"xml"}, false).size();
}

@Override
protected void doStart() throws Exception {
    ServiceHelper.startService(consumerTemplate);

}


@Override
protected void doStop() throws Exception {
    ServiceHelper.stopService(consumerTemplate);

}


@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
     ObjectHelper.notNull(camelContext, "CamelContext", this);         
     camelContext.addService(this);     
}
}
```

The unit test for the preceding tasklet:

```
public class SplitTaskletTest {

@Test public void execute() throws Exception {
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();      

    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {

            Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("nsl", "http://www.toto.fr/orders");
            from("file:data/inbox").id("inbox-road").
            split().
            xtokenize("//nsl:order", 'w', ns, 1000).
            streaming().
            to("file:data/outbox?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${exchangeId}.${file:ext}"); 

        }

    });

    camelContext.start();

    ConsumerTemplate consumer =new DefaultConsumerTemplate(camelContext);

    consumer.start();

    MyCamelTasklet tasklet = new MyCamelTasklet(consumer);

    long debutTraitement = System.currentTimeMillis();

    tasklet.execute(null, null);

    long finTraitement = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long total = finTraitement-debutTraitement;

    File outputDir = new File("data/outbox");
    outputDir.mkdir();

    int nbGeneratesFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(outputDir, new String[]{"xml"}, false).size();

    System.out.println("Traitement total en secondes : "+total/1000);

    Assert.assertTrue(nbGeneratesFiles>0);

}   
}
```